# Why "\n" is true doesn't compare?

Tags: c#, xml, file, compare, match

Look at the sceene here , please:
http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/3600/ 
why it's not matching?

Comment: What's the type of "xml"? Please post code and read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: http://pastebin.com/SDvT6ey3 - code

Comment: @Jon my best guess is XmlNode?

Comment: @Oleg: Please edit it into your question rather than just providing links.

Comment: Okay, now we can see some code, but not enough to reproduce the problem. Please post a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem, and we'll be able to help more.

Comment: The other code isnt' importatnt , because it's only one function. And I call it via: ReadXML(XmlReader.Create(path + delimeter + "config.xml"), new Dictionary<string, string>()); where path is Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) and delimeter is @"\"

Comment: @Oleg: The other code is absolutely important, because we can't reproduce the problem without it. You should give us a minimal example (including data) that we compile and run to demonstrate the problem. Did you read the link in my first comment?

Answer (score 7):

EDIT: Okay, now we know it's [`XmlReader.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.value.aspx), which *does* return a string, that's definitely not the problem. I'll leave the previous answer below for future reference.

My guess is that there are some "odd" Unicode characters which don't show up in the debugger... or that the watch window is behaving strangely. Putting a watch on `xml.Value.ToCharArray()` would help to show that.

(As an aside, giving a `Dictionary<,>` parameter the name `list` is very confusing...)

EDIT: Additionally, using bracing and indentation would *also* make your code easier to follow...

---

We can't tell for sure at the moment, but my *guess* is that the `Value` property is of type `object`, not `string`. That means that `==` and `!=` perform reference comparisons (operators are *overloaded*, not *overridden*, remember). You want the polymorphic behaviour of:

```
if (xml.Value.Equals("\n"))
```

or if `xml.Value` can legitimately be null:

```
if ("\n".Equals(xml.Value))
```

Comment: As an aside, giving a Dictionary<,> parameter the name list is very confusing...), >>>>>>>>>>> why it's confusing?

Comment: @Oleg: Because it's not a list, it's a dictionary! I see "list" I expect an implementation of `IList<T>`...

Comment: Dictonary class is just a list with a lot of <T> - no ?

Comment: @Oleg: No - it's a *mapping* from key to value, instead of a list of values. In particular, lists usually maintain an *ordering* and are accesed either sequentially or by numeric *index*. Maps such as `Dictionary<,>` usually have no inherent order and are accessed by *key*.